# scroll view does not work android

Tags: android

Scroll view does not work help me please ? in simulation in xml work but when i excute the application does not scroll is fixed i use android studio version 3.0.1 and i execute in phone API 25.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cell">

            <ScrollView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/scrollview"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >


          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/s45"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title1"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Rain"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain"
                    />
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/rain_metr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:typeface="normal" />
                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/rain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:touchInside="true"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"
                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title2"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Thunder"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc

                    android:id="@+id/thunder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:touchInside="true"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"

                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image2"

                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/thunder"
                    />
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/thunder_metr"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/s46"
                android:layout_below="@+id/s45"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/title3"

                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Forest"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                    <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                        android:id="@+id/forest"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:padding="30dp"
                        seekarc:startAngle="60"
                        seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                        seekarc:clockwise="false"
                        seekarc:touchInside="true"
                        seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        seekarc:max="100"
                        seekarc:progress="100"

                        seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image3"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/forest"
                        />
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/forest_metr"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="100%"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/title4"

                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="People"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                    <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                        android:id="@+id/people"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:padding="30dp"
                        seekarc:startAngle="60"
                        seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                        seekarc:clockwise="false"
                        seekarc:touchInside="true"
                        seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        seekarc:max="100"
                        seekarc:progress="100"

                        seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image4"

                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/people"
                        />
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/people_metr"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="100%"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/s47"
                android:layout_below="@+id/s46"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/title5"

                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Street"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                    <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                        android:id="@+id/street"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:padding="30dp"
                        seekarc:startAngle="60"
                        seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                        seekarc:clockwise="false"
                        seekarc:touchInside="true"
                        seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        seekarc:max="100"
                        seekarc:progress="100"

                        seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image5"

                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/street"
                        />
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/street_metr"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="100%"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/title6"

                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Raind Drops"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                    <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                        android:id="@+id/rein_drops"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:padding="30dp"
                        seekarc:startAngle="60"
                        seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                        seekarc:clockwise="false"
                        seekarc:touchInside="true"
                        seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        seekarc:max="100"
                        seekarc:progress="100"
                        seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image6"

                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/rain_drops"
                        />
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/rain_drops_metr"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="100%"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/s48"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/s47"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <com.midnight.escape.Text
                            android:id="@+id/title7"

                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Street"
                            android:textSize="10dp"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                        <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                            android:id="@+id/street7"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:padding="30dp"
                            seekarc:startAngle="60"
                            seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                            seekarc:clockwise="false"
                            seekarc:touchInside="true"
                            seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                            seekarc:max="100"
                            seekarc:progress="100"

                            seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image7"

                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/street"
                            />
                        <com.midnight.escape.Text
                            android:id="@+id/street_metr7"

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="100%"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <com.midnight.escape.Text
                            android:id="@+id/title8"

                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Raind Drops"
                            android:textSize="10dp"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                        <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                            android:id="@+id/rein_drops8"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:padding="30dp"
                            seekarc:startAngle="60"
                            seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                            seekarc:clockwise="false"
                            seekarc:touchInside="true"
                            seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                            seekarc:max="100"
                            seekarc:progress="100"
                            seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image8"

                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/rain_drops"
                            />
                        <com.midnight.escape.Text
                            android:id="@+id/rain_drops_metr8"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="100%"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>















           </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>




    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Scroll view does not work help me please ? in simulation in xml work but when i excute the application does not scroll is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Make match_parent layout height

```
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Try like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the tags correctly. Change your layout like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cell"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/s45"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title1"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Rain"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain" />

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/rain_metr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:typeface="normal" />

                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/rain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"
                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    seekarc:touchInside="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title2"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Thunder"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc

                    android:id="@+id/thunder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"
                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

                    seekarc:touchInside="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image2"

                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/thunder" />

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/thunder_metr"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/s46"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/s45"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title3"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Forest"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/forest"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"
                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

                    seekarc:touchInside="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image3"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/forest" />

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/forest_metr"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title4"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="People"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/people"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"
                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

                    seekarc:touchInside="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image4"

                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/people" />

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/people_metr"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/s47"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/s46"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title5"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Street"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/street"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"
                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

                    seekarc:touchInside="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image5"

                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/street" />

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/street_metr"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title6"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Raind Drops"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/rein_drops"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"
                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    seekarc:touchInside="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image6"

                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_drops" />

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/rain_drops_metr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/s48"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/s47"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title7"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Street"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/street7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"
                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

                    seekarc:touchInside="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image7"

                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/street" />

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/street_metr7"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title8"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Raind Drops"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/rein_drops8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"
                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    seekarc:touchInside="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image8"

                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_drops" />

                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/rain_drops_metr8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it your tag is wrong place

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cell">

        <ScrollView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


             <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/s45"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <com.midnight.escape.Text
                android:id="@+id/title1"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rain"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rain"
                />
            <com.midnight.escape.Text
                android:id="@+id/rain_metr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="100%"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:typeface="normal" />
            <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                android:id="@+id/rain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="30dp"
                seekarc:startAngle="60"
                seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                seekarc:clockwise="false"
                seekarc:touchInside="true"
                seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                seekarc:max="100"
                seekarc:progress="100"
                seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <com.midnight.escape.Text
                android:id="@+id/title2"

                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Thunder"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
            <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc

                android:id="@+id/thunder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="30dp"
                seekarc:startAngle="60"
                seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                seekarc:clockwise="false"
                seekarc:touchInside="true"
                seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                seekarc:max="100"
                seekarc:progress="100"

                seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"

                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/thunder"
                />
            <com.midnight.escape.Text
                android:id="@+id/thunder_metr"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="100%"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/s46"
            android:layout_below="@+id/s45"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title3"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Forest"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/forest"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:touchInside="true"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"

                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image3"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/forest"
                    />
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/forest_metr"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title4"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="People"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/people"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:touchInside="true"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"

                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image4"

                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/people"
                    />
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/people_metr"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/s47"
            android:layout_below="@+id/s46"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title5"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Street"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/street"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:touchInside="true"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"

                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image5"

                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/street"
                    />
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/street_metr"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/title6"

                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Raind Drops"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                    android:id="@+id/rein_drops"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    seekarc:startAngle="60"
                    seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                    seekarc:clockwise="false"
                    seekarc:touchInside="true"
                    seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    seekarc:max="100"
                    seekarc:progress="100"
                    seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image6"

                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/rain_drops"
                    />
                <com.midnight.escape.Text
                    android:id="@+id/rain_drops_metr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="100%"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/s48"
                android:layout_below="@+id/s47"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/title7"

                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Street"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                    <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                        android:id="@+id/street7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:padding="30dp"
                        seekarc:startAngle="60"
                        seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                        seekarc:clockwise="false"
                        seekarc:touchInside="true"
                        seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        seekarc:max="100"
                        seekarc:progress="100"

                        seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image7"

                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/street"
                        />
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/street_metr7"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="100%"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/title8"

                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Raind Drops"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/rain_city"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                    <com.midnight.escape.SeekArc
                        android:id="@+id/rein_drops8"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:padding="30dp"
                        seekarc:startAngle="60"
                        seekarc:sweepAngle="240"
                        seekarc:clockwise="false"
                        seekarc:touchInside="true"
                        seekarc:thumbOffset="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        seekarc:max="100"
                        seekarc:progress="100"
                        seekarc:progressWidth="3dp"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image8"

                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/rain_drops"
                        />
                    <com.midnight.escape.Text
                        android:id="@+id/rain_drops_metr8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="100%"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

       </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you closed the scrollview tag in the wrong place

before : `</ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>`

after : `</LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>`